# GDAL: Change no-data value of GeoTIFF without having to recreate the whole GeoTIFF

Tags: python, gdal, google-earth-engine, geotiff-tiff, nodata

I've got a problem with some big GeoTIFFs, that they got no-data value -128, being unsigned. And because of that I can't upload them to GEE, as I am getting an error:

```
Error: No data value -128.0 cannot be applied to band #0 of type Short<0, 255>.
```

Is there an automated way to change these no-data values to something else (basically these files are having max 10, so 255 would be fine I guess; or even 0) without having to recreate the whole datasets (that takes ages, as it's the whole Europe in 10m).

Could be in Python or GDAL tools.

Example gdalinfo of a file (with lower resolution, but having the same problem):

```
Size is 11282, 6117
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["ETRS_1989_LAEA",
    BASEGEOGCRS["ETRS89",
        DATUM["European Terrestrial Reference System 1989",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101004,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4258]],
    CONVERSION["Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area",
        METHOD["Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area",
            ID["EPSG",9820]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",52,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",10,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",4321000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",3210000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    ID["EPSG",3035]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (-1217000.000000000931323,6415000.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (1000.000000000000000,-1000.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-1217000.000, 6415000.000) ( 82d45'43.92"W, 41d20' 9.92"N)
Lower Left  (-1217000.000,  298000.000) ( 40d 5'20.45"W,  9d20'13.32"N)
Upper Right (10065000.000, 6415000.000) (103d45' 8.42"E, 39d27' 3.98"N)
Lower Right (10065000.000,  298000.000) ( 61d46'28.34"E,  8d 9'45.42"N)
Center      ( 4424000.000, 3356500.000) ( 11d32'42.50"E, 53d18'24.09"N)
Band 1 Block=128x128 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  Min=0.000 Max=10.000
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=10.000, Mean=0.206, StdDev=1.248
  NoData Value=-128
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=10
    STATISTICS_MEAN=0.20599296116556
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORX=1
    STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORY=1
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=1.2477841778992
  Image Structure Metadata:
    PIXELTYPE=SIGNEDBYTE
```

Comment: Have you tried gdalwarp?

Comment: gdalwrap tries to reproject/translate (however to call it) it, it takes like 40 hours per file, some even 100+ hours and never finish (ending up in some 200GB files, when original was like 4GB)

Comment: to be clear... we are talking about images that are ~400000x400000 pixels

Comment: 400000 x 400000 pixels makes 160 GB per band as uncompressed if it is an 8 bit image. Don't blame GDAL for that, obviously your original is heavily compressed. And if the original is a striped tiff instead of tiled it requires much more memory. You can check that with gdalinfo. Anyway, gdalwarp does not feel like the best tool.  With gdal_calc it is possible to update the pixel values but updating a compressed image in place may still be very heavy but have a try. Take a small sample first and tune your workflow.

Comment: I am not blaming GDAL, just answering what I tried. Still looking for a solution.

Comment: Please add gdalinfo report about what you have.

Comment: @user30184 added

Comment: looks that it's only about metadata

Comment: to be honest I don't really understand it... it says `PIXELTYPE=SIGNEDBYTE` but GEE thinks it's unsigned.

Comment: If GEE does not like signedbyte then I fear that you must convert the image even it takes some time. What gdalwarp command did you use? Perhaps it can be improved. Is the data something classified because there seems to be only 10 distinct integer values?

Comment: in fact it has only 4 values on every raster  0,1,5,10 (don't ask me why not 1,2,3 or at least bitwise 1,2,4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it seems GEE doesn't understand GDAL's `PIXELDATA` metadata and is treating it as an unsigned datatype regardless, maybe a workaround is just defining the nodata value as the unsigned equivalent to appease GEE.  It sounds like your actual range of values will allow for that.

Note that **this will edit your file in place**, so make a copy if you're worried about that:

`gdal_edit -a_nodata 128 input_file.tif`

Comment: Assigning nodata value does not update anything else than the metadata. Pixels are not changed and the pixeltype will remain as signed byte. If there are really nodata pixels in the data the pixels with value -128 will remain there.

Comment: That's the point.  If you take the binary representation of `-128` and treat it as an unsigned integer (precisely what GEE is trying to do) you get `128`

Comment: I think it's fine for me so it would only change the meta for nodata, I don't think I actually have no-data values anywhere, I'll test it.